# Management company's landscaping team are working too much ... what can I do?

Tags: landlord, wisconsin, noise

**Background**: I have lived in a rental apartment in a quiet neighborhood of Shorewood, in Milwaukee county, WI, for eight years. The rent is relatively high but living in a quiet areas makes it worth it. There are 20+ apartments and each 2 stories. About two years ago the owner of all the apartments passed away and his kids passed the management to a relatively large apartment management company.

**Problem**: Since then, the landscaping team from the management company comes between 3 to 4 days a week from 8am to 4:30pm with lawn mower, trimmer and leaf blower to do the "landscaping". It is becoming ridiculous. I don't think grass grows that fast such that it needs landscaping 3 to 4 times a week. It is ridiculous, distracting and they make a lot of noise.

**My attempt**: I tried emailing/calling the management numerous times complaining but no success. Management company says their landscaping team is professional and if they are working 3 to 4 days a week, then it is because grasses need landscaping. I assume the landscaping team are getting paid hourly which would explain the situation.

**Question**: What options do I have besides simply renting/moving to another apartment?

Answer (score 1):

You have no options other than those you have already utilized. Management of the common elements of a property that you rent is something in the sole discretion of the landlord.

The noise would have to be so problematic that it makes it impossible for anyone to live in the apartment and constitute a constructive eviction for you to have any remedy, and even then, the normal remedy for a tenant would be to let you out of your lease early.